# How to hide Creation Date from WHOIS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, whois, registrar

Amazon Route53 hides most of the contact information by default, however that doesn't include the Creation Date property. Is there an option to hide that piece of information as well? I do not want the public to know when I created my website.

Comment: The creation date of the domain name and the date the website was published are two different things though. If you are concerned with credibility because your domain name is brand new, you could buy an older domain at some marketplace. Otherwise I don't know why you are worried about domain creation date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you did not mention the top level domain (TLD) you're referring to. In case of e.g. .com (or another gTLD), you can not avoid having the creation date in WHOIS. See [Appendix F](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/gtld-registration-data-specs-en/#appendixF) of the [Temporary Specification for gTLD Registration Data](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/gtld-registration-data-specs-en), being effective as of 25 May 2018, for more details.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was referring to .com domains.